# Making a BarChart of a Two Column Dataset

Tags: charts

If I have a 2-column dataset like:

[image]

How do I make a `BarChart` in the obvious way (i.e., bars labeled by FileName, in this case)?

Answer (score 2):

Several ways to do it:

```
dataset[BarChart[Labeled[#, Rotate[#2, 90 Degree], Axis]&@@@#]&,{"FileSize", "FileName"}]

dataset[BarChart[#[[All, 1]], ChartLabels -> (Rotate[#, 90 Degree]& /@ #[[All,2]])]&, 
  {"FileSize", "FileName"}]

dataset // Query[BarChart[#[[All, 1]], 
   ChartLabels -> (Rotate[#, 90 Degree]& /@ #[[All,2]])]&, {"FileSize", "FileName"}]

BarChart[#, ChartLabels -> Placed[#2, Axis, Rotate[#, 90 Degree]&]]& @@ 
  dataset[Transpose, {"FileSize", "FileName"}]
```

Comment: It turns out this causes collision in the BarChart due to outliers: [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/user-900a994f-78ab-4931-b18e-353eff4d0b33/collision.png). Is there a way to account for this? Maybe only the top few files can be shown cleanly?

Comment: @George, does `ScalingFunctions->"Log"` (in BarChart) help?

Comment: A bit but there's still considerable collision in the labeling.

Comment: you can  use `dataset[BarChart[Labeled[#, Rotate[#2, 90 Degree], Axis]& @@@ #]&, {"FileSize","FileName"}]` to have the labels rotated.

Comment: kglr: That worked! Is there a way to make the y-axis have units in Mb instead of bytes?

Comment: @George, maybe you can just multiply the input data by 10^6 (or 2^20?); e.g., `dataset[BarChart[Labeled[10^6 #, Rotate[#2, 90 Degree], Axis]&@@@#]&,{"FileSize", "FileName"}]`??